# Confirmation box javascript

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

Problem:

I have a confirmation box which pops up whenever I click on the save button. It saves the data fine when I click on OK. But when I click on cancel it does not cancel changes. It saves them instead. Could you please help me solve this issue:

Here is the JavaScript for it:

```
/
<asp:Button ID="view_btn_save" Text="Save" ValidationGroup="view" OnClick="view_btn_save_click"
                        OnClientClick="Validate_view()" runat="server"
                        />                        
                </td>
                <script type="text/javascript">
                    function Validate_view() {
                        var value = document.getElementById('<%=view_txt_name.ClientID%>').value;
                        var value2 = document.getElementById('<%=view_txt_title.ClientID%>').value;
                        var value3 = document.getElementById('<%=view_txt_description.ClientID%>').value;
                        var value4 = document.getElementById('<%=view_txt_pixelwidth.ClientID%>').value;
                        var value5 = document.getElementById('<%=view_txt_pixelheight.ClientID%>').value;

                        if (value == '' || value2 == '' || value3 == '' || value4 == '' || value5 == '') {
                            return alert('Please enter the missing fields');
                        }                        
                        else {
                            return confirm('Confirm changes?');
                        }
                    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add a return statement to the `OnClientClick` declaration:

```
OnClientClick="return Validate_view();"
```

In the case where you show an alert, I would change your code to this:

```
alert("...");
return false;
```

**EDIT**: Here's a full example

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    function Validate_view() { 
        var value = document.getElementById('<%=view_txt_name.ClientID%>').value; 
        var value2 = document.getElementById('<%=view_txt_title.ClientID%>').value; 
        var value3 = document.getElementById('<%=view_txt_description.ClientID%>').value; 
        var value4 = document.getElementById('<%=view_txt_pixelwidth.ClientID%>').value; 
        var value5 = document.getElementById('<%=view_txt_pixelheight.ClientID%>').value; 

        if (value == '' || value2 == '' || value3 == '' || value4 == '' || value5 == '') { 
            alert('Please enter the missing fields'); 
            return false;
        }                         
        else { 
            return confirm('Confirm changes?'); 
        } 
    } 
</script>
<asp:Button ID="view_btn_save" runat="server" Text="Save" OnClientClick="return Validate_view()" OnClick="view_btn_save_click" />
```

Comment: Rightnow, what is happening is, after i click ok in the alert box it runs a stored procedure to save the data when it should not. It should only perform that action when return confirm(...) is true. Any suggestions on how to stop this?

Comment: Yes, you just need to add the return statement to your `OnClientClick`, and return false after the alert is shown. Everything you need should be in my answer.

Comment: This is happening after I have tried out your code. I added the exact same thing but it is giving me an error i mentioned above anyway.

Comment: I updated with a full example. Try removing `ValidationGroup` from the button. Validation might be overriding `OnClientClick`.

Comment: It works! Thank you so much!!! I was doing return alert and then return false. But it works now thanks a ton!!